# How do I resolve this error when upgrading a vuejs app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a old vuejs app that I'm trying to upgrade from 1.0.28 to 2.5.16.

The following code doesn't work for 2.5.16 but is working for 1.0.28.

**html**

```
<a class="button" v-on:click="selectPage(this.pagination.currentPage-1)" v-bind:class="{'is-disabled': this.pagination.currentPage==this.pagination.items[0] || this.pagination.items.length==0}">Previous</a>
<a class="button" v-on:click="selectPage(this.pagination.currentPage+1)" v-bind:class="{'is-disabled': this.pagination.currentPage==this.pagination.items[this.pagination.items.length-1] || this.pagination.items.length==0}">Next page</a>
```

**Method**

```
selectPage(item) {
      this.pagination.currentPage = item
      
      let start = 0
      let end = 0
      if(this.pagination.currentPage < this.pagination.range-2){
        start = 1
        end = start+this.pagination.range-1
      }
      else if(this.pagination.currentPage <= this.pagination.items.length && this.pagination.currentPage > this.pagination.items.length - this.pagination.range + 2){
        start = this.pagination.items.length-this.pagination.range+1
        end = this.pagination.items.length
      }
      else{
        start = this.pagination.currentPage-2
        end = this.pagination.currentPage+2
      }
      if(start<1){
        start = 1
      }
      if(end>this.pagination.items.length){
        end = this.pagination.items.length
      }
      
      this.pagination.filteredItems = []
      for(var i=start; i<=end; i++){
        this.pagination.filteredItems.push(i);
      }
      
      this.paginatedItems = this.filteredItems.filter((v, k) => {
        return Math.ceil((k+1) / this.pagination.itemPerPage) == this.pagination.currentPage
      })
    },
```

I see the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPage' of undefined
    at click (eval at createFunction (vue.js:10667), <anonymous>:3:1514)
    at invoker (vue.js:2029)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.js:1828)
```

How would I get this to work with vue 2.5.16?

**Solution**
Change to the following:

```
<a class="button" v-on:click="selectPage(pagination.currentPage-1)" v-bind:class="{'is-disabled': pagination.currentPage==this.pagination.items[0] || this.pagination.items.length==0}">Previous</a>
    <a class="button" v-on:click="selectPage(pagination.currentPage+1)" v-bind:class="{'is-disabled': pagination.currentPage==this.pagination.items[this.pagination.items.length-1] || this.pagination.items.length==0}">Next page</a>
```

Comment: Show where you define `pagination` at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `this.pagination.currentPage` by `pagination.currentPage` in your template